# ASP.NET MVC 4 Custom model validation

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, model

I've read a lot of documentation about adding custom validation attributes to a property of a model. Since I have a database first EF generated model, I would implement a partial class using metadata so that the code wont't get wiped in a model update. Just like in this sample : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_dcfw1btK0

My question is : what if the field that I want to validate already have annotation in the generated class ? Like [StringLength(75)] and [DataMember]. Is my partial definition act as an override and apply the base annotation or is it just a plain shadow that will totally hide the one generated by EF ?